# VariationMatrix error with configurable product in admin

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1

When trying to edit a configurable product I'm given the error `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php on line 39` which prevents anything from showing:

[image]

I'm at a loss as to what's causing this and how to fix it.

Comment: It's not really helpful but a client of ours just started running into this issue today. It seems to be on a duplicated product so it might be something to do with that.

Answer (score 8):

The problem in our case was we had a configurable product set to use two configurable attributes. However, one or more of the simple products that were associated did not have a value for the configurable attribute. Presumably, the products did have this value at one point but the values were removed after the product had been linked up.

The solution was to populate the simple product attribute values. This means you can then edit the configurable product and remove that configurable attribute from the product if required.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I noticed that the `configurable attribute` is not present in that `attribute set`

Edit the Attribute Set and add the configurable attribute in this set to be used by Variants.

Comment: this answer works for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have alot of variations!! It could possible be a resource issue that it's unable to load variations. You can check value of `max_input_vars` and increase in `php.ini` file to something higher like 5000.

Comment: There are only 10 variations.

Answer (score 0):

Delete affected configurable products and then reimport. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code in line number **39**

**From:**

```
$filledVariation[$currentAttribute['id']] = $currentAttribute['values'][$currentVariationValue];
```

**To:**

```
if(isset($currentAttribute['id']) && $currentAttribute['id']) {
   $filledVariation[$currentAttribute['id']] = $currentAttribute['values'][$currentVariationValue]; 
}
```

**Note:** First override `VariationMatrix.php` file in local after change above code.

Comment: This doesnt not work in magento 2.2.3

Comment: doesn't work for me for Magento V2.2.4!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and got resolved.
Only need to check "configurable_variation" column. Put proper corelation amongst simple products.