# I am using Magento 2.3.5, after I imported products, when I try to edit a configurable product I am getting the below. How do I fix it?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, products

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/app/current/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php on line 47

Comment: Follow this url may be help full to you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144954/variationmatrix-error-with-configurable-product-in-admin

It's issues regarding configurable attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check below solution.

```
app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php
```

Removed this line: `$filledVariation[$currentAttribute['id']] = $currentAttribute['values'][$currentVariationValue];`

added this new line: `if(isset($currentAttribute['id']) && $currentAttribute['id']) {`